# How to to trigger useEffects on windows.variable Global Variable change

Tags: reactjs, jsx, use-effect

I am loading the two files and i have a variable called routes that i want to have changed base on a click from another component. I have a global variable called window.showhide thats boolen and another one window.route which is an object array. i want to toggle window.showhide from another component and have useEffect trigger. using window.showhide useEffects does not trigger. i just want to change  window.route to route2 from another component. please help me figure this out.

```
import route1 from "./routes1"
import route2 from ".routes2"
window.showhide = false
window.route = route1
const routes = window.route

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
     if(window.showhide){
         routes = route2
     } else {
         routes = route1
    }
  }, [window.showhide]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` does not have the ability to listen for variables to change, and then cause a rerender of your component. Rather, your component has to *already* be rerendering due to something else, and then the dependency array decides whether or not to run the extra code found in the useEffect.

If you want to render a component in react, you need to set state. So the typical solution for your kind of problem is to have a state variable in App, and then pass down a function that lets a child set that state.

```
export default function App() {
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState(route1);

  const showHide = useCallback((value) => {
    setRoutes(value ? route1 : route2);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ChildComponent showHide={showHide} />
  );
}

// In the child:
function ChildComponent({ showHide }) {
  return <div onClick={() => showHide(true)} />
}
```

If the components are very far removed from eachother, then passing down via props may be a pain, in which case you can use context instead:

```
const ShowHideContext = createContext(() => {});

export default function App() {
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState(route1);

  const showHide = useCallback((value) => {
    setRoutes(value ? route1 : route2);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ShowHideContext.Provider value={showHide}>
      <ChildComponent />
    </ShowHideContext.Provider>
  );
}

// Elsewhere:

function Example () {
  const showHide = useContext(ShowHideContext);

  return <button onClick={() => showHide(true)} />
}
```

Comment: I have one problem  i get showHide is not a function error in my browser., how can i get around that. Thank you for the help by the way